# Python for loop intuition

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm iterating over a list using for loop in python. I'm not able to get what is happening in this scenario.

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a:
   print(a)
```

output->

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Imagine you did `for x in a`.  Then the variable `x` would be given the value of each element of `a` in turn, right?  First time round the loop, `x` is `a[0]`, second time `x` is `a[1]` and so on.  Well here, `a[-1]` (the last element of `a`) is set to `a[0]` in the first iteration of the loop, `a[-1]` is set to `a[1]` in the second iteration of the loop, and so on...

Comment: What are you trying to do and what's your expected output?

Comment: Suggest to try this great visual platform next time for small  program - https://pythontutor.com/           Learning how to debug is super important!

Comment: @slothrop I was just trying to understand how will this for loop works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this for loop, you are setting `a[-1]`, which is the last item in the list `a`, to be the currently iterated object.

The result becomes clear when walking through step by step.

`a = [0, 1, 2, 3]`

**First iteration**
Currently iterating: `0`
Sets the last object in `a` to `0`, meaning that:
a = [**0**, 1, 2, **0**]

**Second iteration**
Currently iterating: `1`
Sets the last object in `a` to `1`, meaning that:
a = [0, **1**, 2, **1**]

**Third iteration**
Currently iterating: `2`
Sets the last object in `a` to `2`, meaning that:
a = [0, 1, **2**, **2**]

**Fourth iteration**
In the fourth iteration, you are just setting the last item in a to itself, meaning nothing changes.  This explains why you got the output you did.

Comment: Nice explanation.  The example can be seen more clearly using `for a[0] in …`.

Comment: As further context, this assignment works as lists are mutable; or more specifically, accept element assignment.  This will *not* work with an immutable type such as a string or tuple.